# Expected value of the number of pattern in sequence

Tags: probability, expected-value, independence, uniform-distribution

We have set of letters: $\{A,C,G,T\}$. We draw uniformly independently with returning $n \ge 7$ letters. Let $X_i$ be the result of $i-th$ draw. In other words: we have $n$ independent random variables with distribution $\mathbb{P}(X_i=A)=\mathbb{P}(X_i=C)=\mathbb{P}(X_i=G)=\mathbb{P}(X_i=T)=\frac{1}{4}$.
Let $Y_n$ be random variable counting the number of pattern: $\left( A,?,A\right)$ in sequence $\left(X_1, \ldots, X_n\right)$ (where $?$ is one of the letters: $A,C,G,T$).

For example in sequence $ \left(A,C,A,T,A,T,G\right)$, $n=7$, we have $Y_7=2$.

Calculate $\mathbb{E}Y_n$.

I have no idea how to even start with this task. I need your help.

Comment: **Hint:** Linearity of expectation is very powerful.  How might you use it here?  Ignoring all other positions at the moment except the first and the third, what is the probability that the first is an $A$ and the third is an $A$?

Comment: Thank you! I finally did it. It took me almost 5 hours :O.

Comment: if the sequence observed was $\left(A,A,A,A,A,A,A\right)$  what would $Y_7$ be?  Technicalities with overlaps can make this a lot trickier than just linearity of expectations.

Comment: @user8675309 by my interpretation, it would be $5$.  I see no reason to stipulate that it be anything but

Comment: @JMoravitz I mostly have the same interpretation.  That said it is extremely common to look at disjoint patterns so linguistic clarity is helpful,

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @JMoravitz:

I define $Z_i$ such that $Z_i=1$ when pattern start at $i-th$ place and $Z_i=0$ otherwise. Then we have $$Y_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2}Z_i$$
It's obvious that $\mathbb{P}\left(Z_i=1\right)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{4}$ and $\mathbb{E}Z_i=\frac{1}{16}$.
$$\mathbb{E}Y_n = \mathbb{E}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2}Z_i= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2}\mathbb{E}Z_i = \frac{n-2}{16}$$

Comment: That's exactly the solution I had in mind.  Good job.